# multithread in Java Rmi

Tags: java, multithreading, rmi

I was wondering how to use threads with RMI. For example how to make the following Java RMI Simple code become multithreaded?

Interface:

```
public interface NntpServerInterface extends Remote
{
    String Hello() throws  RemoteException;
}
```

Interface implementation:

```
public class NntpServerImpl  extends UnicastRemoteObject implements NntpServerInterface
{
  public   NntpServerImpl() throws RemoteException
  {
  }

  public String Hello()
  {
      return "Hello" ;
  }
}
```

and where I can run main server:

```
public class NntpServerRun {
    static Registry reg;

    public static void main(String args []) throws RemoteException, AlreadyBoundException
    {
        reg=LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1111);
        reg.bind("NntpServer", new NntpServerImpl());
        System.out.println("Nntp Server  Started........");
    }
}
```

and finally the client side:

```
public class Client 
{
    static Registry reg;
    static NntpServerInterface ci;

    public static void main(String args )
    {
        reg=LocateRegistry.getRegistry(jTextField1.getText(), 1111);
        ci=(NntpServerInterface)(reg.lookup("NntpServer"));
        System.out.print(ci.Hello());
    }
}
```

Is it possible to  change the above code to be multithreaded? I heard that RMI is already multithreaded.

Comment: RMI is already using multiple threads and it is thread safe.  SO you don't have to do anything to make it multi-threaded.  Can you clarify what you are trying to do?

Comment: @PeterLawrey It is already multi-threaded, but thread safety is in the eye of the beholder, or the programmer in this case :-)

Answer (score 1):

> I heard that RMI is already multithreaded.

You are correct. No change is necessary to this code. In general it is up to you to ensure thread-safety of your remote objects, but this particular one is already thread-safe.

Comment: Why do you say 'is already thread-safe'? Is it because he is not using any state or static fields?

Comment: @Teddy Because he isn't using any volatile unsynchronized shared resources in his remote method implementation.